# Are intermediate results piped using _ in chained operations available to subsequent functions in the chain?

Tags: python, pandas, chaining

I am creating a correlation matrix from which I want to obtain the max positive correlation value. Applying max() to the `corr()` results will just return 1.0 for the correlations along the axis, which is not desired, and so the objective is to remove all occurrences of 1.0 and then run the `max()`. I was thinking to do this in a chained operation, and can do it using _ to pipe intermediate results to the `where()` operation, which does turn 1.0 into NaNs. However, applying `max()` as the next operation in the chain still returns 1.0 as though it is ignoring the results of the `where()`.

Is there something I'm not understanding with the _ operator? Or perhaps `where()` is the wrong function in this context? I have provided full code below to reproduce the question.

```
# Set up the problem

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# raw data

raw_t = [
66.6, 36.4, 47.6, 17.0, 54.6, 21.0, 12.2, 13.6, 20.6, 55.4, 63.4, 69.0,
80.2, 26.2, 42.6, 31.8, 15.6, 27.8, 13.8, 22.0, 14.2, 62.6, 96.4, 113.8,
115.2,82.2, 65.0, 23.2, 24.0, 14.2,  1.4,  3.8, 16.4, 16.4, 67.0, 51.4
]

# raw indexes

yr_mn = (np.full(12, 2000).tolist() + np.full(12, 2001).tolist() + np.full(12, 2002).tolist(),
np.arange(1,13).tolist() + np.arange(1,13).tolist() + np.arange(1,13).tolist() )

# structure multi index

index_base = list(zip(*yr_mn))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_base, names=["year", "month"])

# create indexed dataset

t_dat = pd.Series(raw_t, index=index)

# example of the correlation matrix we are working with

pd.set_option("format.precision", 2)
t_dat.unstack().corr().style.background_gradient(cmap="YlGnBu")
```

And my attempts:

```
t_dat.unstack().corr().stack().where(_!=1.0) # does swap out 1.0 for NaN  
t_dat.unstack().corr().stack().where(_!=1.0).max() # still returns 1.0
```

Another point is that it will sometimes work, but sometimes it doesn't, returning
`ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self`

This also makes me suspicious that I am missing something. The default setting of panda's `max()` is to skip NaNs, so it shouldn't have anything to do with that. I also tried setting the 1.0 to 0.0 using `where(_!=1.0,0.0)`; same result. Also, I found the ValueError can be overcome if I rem out the where and rerun, as:

```
t_dat.unstack().corr().stack()#.where(\_!=1.0)
```

This somehow resets it, even though the original dataframe is not being altered.

Thanks for any insights!
David

Comment: Are you running your code through interactive Python shell? Then the underscore `_` contains the result of last command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `_` in interactive environments - this contains the result of last command (it could work but eventually it will break).

You can do this:

```py
# store the result to a variable:
result = t_dat.unstack().corr().stack()

# compute the boolean mask and set the True values to NaN
mask = result == 1.0
result[mask] = np.nan

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
...
11     1       -0.148800
       2       -0.561202
       3       -0.595797
       4        0.945831
       5       -0.737437
       6        0.812018
       7        0.516614
       8        0.785324
       9       -0.823919
       10       0.539078
       11            NaN
       12       0.929903
12     1       -0.502081
       2       -0.826288
       3       -0.849431
       4        0.760119
       5       -0.437322
       6        0.969761
       7        0.795323
       8        0.957978
       9       -0.557725
       10       0.811077
       11       0.929903
       12            NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

Then you can compute the `max`:

```
print(result.max())
```

Prints:

```
0.9996502197746994
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was thinking to do it with a nice big chain, but there are limits I suppose. I hadn't realized the limitation of _ in interactive environments - time for some more reading!